# Angular2 RC "NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays." error

Tags: angular

I have an Angular2 app running version 2.0.0-rc.2.

When I use the below http get call in a service I am getting an error saying "NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.". There are more details of the error at the bottom of the post.
I am calling a .net Web Api end point.
When the service is pointed to a json file the app works as expected.
Does anyone have any ideas?

This is the service call...

```
getTiles(): Observable<ITile[]> {      
  return this._http.get(this._tileUrl)
        .map((response: Response) => <ITile[]> response.json())
        .do(data => console.log('All: ' +  JSON.stringify(data)))
        .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

Here is more details about the error...

> '[{"TileId":2119799133,"Title":"The Old Doctor Butlers
>   Head"},{"TileId":2132951783,"Title":"Milk Tea &
>   Pearl"},{"TileId":2139685810,"Title":""}]' **of type 'string'. NgFor
>   only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.**

The component that uses this service subscribes like this...

```
 ngOnInit(): void {
       this._TilesService.getTiles()
                 .subscribe(
                   tiles => this.tiles = tiles,
                   error =>  this.errorMessage = <any>error); 
}
```

And contains this HTML...

```
 <div *ngFor="let t of tiles">
   <tile [tile]='t'></tile>
 </div>
```

Comment: Post the html please.

Comment: And the relevant component code.

Comment: All this should be in the question, properly formatted.

Comment: Done, I have updated the question.

Comment: Is the response type from the Web API `application/json`'?

Comment: Can't reproduce this in my Plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/ShGiunqLpTbPX6DfLPvz?p=preview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your ideas. I've solved the issue. It was on the Web Api side. The content was being manually serialized but that's not needed as Web Api will take care of this. This was leading to bad formatting in the returned content. This line was removed...

```
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(tiles);
```